# SQL How do I select plans not associated with any country

Tags: sql-server

Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1acd1/2

I'm passing UserId to get User's countryid so I can fetch plans according to user's country.

I have plans specific to countries but I don't have plans for all countries so when I pass userid where I don't have any plan for that user/country at the moment no rows returns but in that case I need to show default plans (plans with country id = '1') to that user.

Please see fiddle, In case of userid='4' no rows returns so in that case I need to show default plans to that user. all default plans have countryid=1

I hope you understand my question :) thanks

Comment: what are the `default plans`? 
    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it.

I took a different approach and started from the `tblProfile` because your input for this query is actually a `UserId` so I found it more logical to follow this process:

1. For the `UserId`, fetch `PlanId` of his `CountryId`
2. If User's `CountryId` does not exist in `lstCountry` or has no `PlanId` replace User's `CountryId` by the default `CountryId=1` (as mentioned in the comments below)
3. Finally, fetch Plan details and Currency for the final `CountryId`

**Tables definitions**

```
CREATE TABLE lstCountry(
CountryID int,
CountryTitle varchar(100),
CurrencyCode varchar(3))

INSERT INTO lstCountry (CountryId, CountryTitle, CurrencyCode) VALUES 
(1, 'USA', 'USD'),
(2, 'GB', 'GBP'),
(3, 'France', 'EUR')

CREATE TABLE tblProfile(
UserId int,
CountryId int)

INSERT INTO tblProfile (UserId, CountryId) VALUES 
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(4, 4)

CREATE TABLE tblPlan (
PlanId int,
PlanTitle nvarchar(50),
PlanPrice money,
CountryId int)

INSERT INTO tblPlan (PlanId, PlanTitle, PlanPrice, CountryId) VALUES 
(1, 'PlanDefault', 10, 1),
(2, 'Plan2', 20, 2),
(3, 'Plan3', 30, 3),
(4, 'PlanDefault', 40, 1),
(5, 'Plan5', 50, 2)
```

**Query**

```
select distinct f.PlanId,
f.PlanTitle,
f.PlanPrice,
e.CurrencyCode
from (
  select case when c.PlanId is null then '1' else a.CountryId end as CountryId
  from tblProfile a
  left join lstCountry b on a.CountryId=b.CountryId
  left join tblPlan c on b.CountryId=c.CountryId
  where UserId=4
) d
inner join lstCountry e on d.CountryId=e.CountryId
inner join tblPlan f on d.CountryId=f.CountryId
```

Result for `UserId=1`:

```
| PlanId |   PlanTitle | PlanPrice | CurrencyCode |
|--------|-------------|-----------|--------------|
|      1 | PlanDefault |        10 |          USD |
|      4 | PlanDefault |        40 |          USD |
```

Result for `UserId=2`

```
| PlanId | PlanTitle | PlanPrice | CurrencyCode |
|--------|-----------|-----------|--------------|
|      2 |     Plan2 |        20 |          GBP |
|      5 |     Plan5 |        50 |          GBP |
```

Result for `UserId=3`

```
| PlanId | PlanTitle | PlanPrice | CurrencyCode |
|--------|-----------|-----------|--------------|
|      3 |     Plan3 |        30 |          EUR |
```

Result for `UserId=4`

```
| PlanId |   PlanTitle | PlanPrice | CurrencyCode |
|--------|-------------|-----------|--------------|
|      1 | PlanDefault |        10 |          USD |
|      4 | PlanDefault |        40 |          USD |
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7068c/8/0

Comment: Thanks but to clarify '226' is countryID not planID. 

I’m passing @UserId to get User’s Country and based on CountryId I’m getting Plans and CurrencyCode specific to that User / Country

I have plans but not for all Countries so if a user’s countryId not associated with any plan I need to show default plans to the user. Default plans have country id ‘226’

So show plans which have countryid = to user’s country id if not found show plans with countryid = ‘225’

Comment: Ok understood, I'll update my answer accordingly. One more question. In case the country of the user does not have a plan, do you still want to select the `CurrencyCode` of the user's country or do you want the `CurrencyCode` of the default country (226)?

Comment: CurrencyCode of the default country (226)

Comment: @GeoConcepts I don't understand where the 225 value comes from in your previous comment but I have updated the answer and the link to the fiddle so that when a User's country has no plan, the query returns the default plan (3) for the default country (226). Does that answer your question?

Comment: I have updated http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1acd1/2 in case of  userid='4' no rows returns so in that case I need to show default plans to that user. default plans have countryid=1 in that fiddle schema

Comment: @GeoConcepts I've updated the answer above to answer your question.

Comment: @ Alexis.Rolland Thank you very much :) very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `LEFT JOIN` and second parse of the table might achieve this. If not, then please look at @JuanCarlosOropeza comments and update your post with Sample and expected data.

```
SELECT p.PlanId,
       p.PlanTitle,
       p.PlanPrice,
       ISNULL(c.CurrencyCode, d.CurrencyCode) AS CurrencyCode
FROM tblPlan p
     LEFT JOIN lstCountry c ON c.CountryId = p.CountryId
     LEFT JOIN lstCountry d ON c.CountryId IS NULL
                           AND d.CountryId = 226
WHERE P.CountryId = (SELECT sq.CountryId
                     FROM tblProfile sq --Not sure if this requires a Default Country
                     WHERE  UserId = @UserId) 
  AND p.IsVisible = '1';
```

Comment: This does not work in my opinion, I've tested your query with the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15a3b9/16/0 for `UserId=3` in the example data set it should return the default plan and it returns nothing instead.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland what data did you use to test this..? We haven't had any from the OP.

Comment: I've made up some test data to reproduce the situation described in the question. You can see it in the fiddle or in my answer below.

Comment: But that's **your** data, based on what you think the OP's data is, not the OP's. I'll be happy to accept your comments if we had data from the OP, but we don't have anything to work on. Hence my request for sample and expected data in the post.